# Доказать что ты человек. Причем не любой, а именно данный

Tags: алгоритм, регистрация, аутентификация, теория, блокчейн

Вопрос теоретический.

Допустим я хочу хорошо управлять своим предприятием, при том под хорошим управлением я понимаю заставить функционировать его так, чтобы его деятельность удовлетворяла, как можно большее число людей.
Разумным решением видится дать возможность всем желающим высказать свои пожелания, пролайкать/дизлайкать чужие пожелания. Далее следует ранжировать пожелания в порядке убывания заинтересованности, и оценивать работу управления предприятием в соответствии с тем как успешно оно закрывает данную повестку, делая не интересными для опрашиваемых строчки из верхней части списка.

Далее, если хочется создавать надежный инструмент для подобной системы агрегации желаний, следует избавиться от возможных злоупотреблений: использовать блокчейн вместо БД, не позволять одному, обновляемому ПО быть у всех пользователей- исключить Атаку 51% проводимую по средствам накатывания обновления, позволить всем желающим участвовать в процессе. И вот здесь возникает вопрос: Как создать аутентификацию, которая:

1. Однозначно отличит одного человека от другого.
2. Не содержит частей, которые требуют обработки человеком, или частей в которые может вмешиваться человек.
3. Не позволит наплодить искусственных личностей. Т.е. не только однозначно отличает человека от другого человека, но еще и человека от скрипта.

Кажется утопией, но криптовалюты тоже казались таковой, а сейчас они функционируют.  Может и алгоритм аутентификации Proof of Human, или как лучше такое называть, существует?

Как создать такую аутентификацию?

В соответствии с идеями возникшими в комментариях можно представить например такой вариант: возможно существует некая информация, которую можно извлекать из человека многократно разными способами...
Например представим что такой информацией, которую нельзя подделать является голос(исключительно для примера). В таком случае, для стойкого распознавания, блокчейном генерируется слово, которое должен произнести человек для аутентификации. При чем, некая характеристика голоса, например тембр, должен обладать следующими свойствами:

1. Уникальность для каждого человека.
2. Невозможность искусственной генерации(самое сложное- мы можем сгенерить почти все).
3. Относительная легкость проверки соответствия "тембра" ранее внесенному.

При таких условиях сам человек как-бы будет являться секретным ключом от электронной подписи.

Приходит в голову старая нерешенная задача про просчет структуры белка, Парадокс Левинталя и все в этом духе. Может биоинформатики подскажут есть ли возможность такой криптографии на основе упаковки белка?

Comment: *Как создать такую аутентификацию?* Да никак. Во-первых, у человека не так много однозначно идентифицируемых признаков, и далеко не все из них доступны к проверке комп. средствами. Во-вторых, процесс сверки признака подвержен и подделке, и ошибке (ну человеческий фактор).

Comment: @Akina Да в лоб никак конечно. Вероятно почти каждый понимает ваши аргументы, возможно вы и правы. Но,  думаю что про крипту так-же(что невозможно создать) не раз говорили, а вообще в старину про капчи...

Comment: Всё давно придумано - УКЭП

Comment: @MadJackal Как УКЭП выдавать не прибегая к людям и БД в этом и вопрос.

Comment: Кроме того, Вам (если Вы сам себе злобный Буратино) ничто не мешает раздать свою УКЭП куче других людей (или скриптов), и они начнут успешно прикидываться Вами.

Comment: Как насчет действовать от противного? Мне хочется думать, что легче поймать искусственную имитацию, и идентифицировать её как ИИ, чем доказывать человечность человекАв. Простейшее отличие это наличие исходного кода у ИИ, коего у нас нет. А после легко понять, что перед нами человек, не заморачиваясь есть ли у него кожа и запах :)

Comment: @tomato-magnet-regulato Отлично было бы- умные тараканы тоже смогли бы поучаствовать...  :) Не могли бы развернуть что вы имеете ввиду? Как проверить что у того кто входит в контакт, например с блокчейном, есть код?

Answer (score 8):

Неожиданно, мне вопрос понравился, до такой степени, что я рискну порассуждать о нём.

В более короткой форме вопрос можно свести к тому, как отличить "настоящего человека" от "цифровой имитации" (в разных смыслах: и в том, что "имитация" может в десяти разных интернет - магазинах делать заказы, и в том смысле, что "имитация" может зарегистрироваться на форуме, активно там жить и никто не будет знать, что за имитацией нет отдельного человека.

Очевидно, "дистанционно" этого не сделать никак. Если хорошо симулировать - никто не отличит симумяцию от человека.

Вот при личной встрече - на человека можно посмотреть, его можно понюхать, пощупать, попросить у него паспорт...

И договориться с ним о чем то, что может потом уже *дистанционно* идентифицировать его причем именно как этого, которого вы нюхали...

Пускай Вы лично встретитесь с каждым, в ком хотите быть уверены, и выдаёте ему половинку секретного ключа. Теперь каждый, кто вам дистанционно эту половинку скажет - будет идентифицирован, и простая половина задачи решена.

(заметим, что фактически именно этот "алгоритм" реализуется в упоминаемой УКЭП - её получают по паспорту в неком удостоверяющем центре, её хранят у себя и предъявляют, когда хотят доказать, что вы - это вы)

Но сложная часть задачи - осталась: как препятствовать этому человеку раздать свою пловинку ключа еще куче людей или виртуальных личностей?

Продолжим рассуждение. Пускай, когда Вы лично встречались - вы еще и взяли у человека его номер телефона. Со словами "я тебе потом позвоню!".

Теперь, когда Вы хотите удостовериться, что человек "на том конце линии" действительно тот, за кого себя выдаёт - вы можете ему позвонить (или послать SMS с кодом) и удостовериться, что это он.

Это - старая добрая двухфакторная аутентификация, которая, однако основана на двух вещах: 1) уникальности телефонных номеров (sim-карт и т.п.) 2) отсутствии у идентифицируемого желания дублировать свой "второй фактор" (иначе, он мог бы создать рассылку "второго фактора" всем, кому может понадобится прикинуться им, и two factor authentification не сработала бы)

Comment: "Пускай Вы лично встретитесь с каждым, в ком хотите быть уверены" - тогда агентом, который сможет злоупотреблять своим положением стану я - голосующие смогут обоснованно не доверять системе пологая что я все подделываю. Что возможно и не критично для многих ситуаций, но подрывает идею системы без злоупотреблений, хотя, конечно, возможно, и удовлетворительным образом.

Comment: Да, тут напрашивается какой то симметиричный алгоритм... какая то лихая комбинация ssh и nft-токенов, но не таких. которые "где то зарегистрированы", а таких, которые "на самом деле" существуют в единственном экземпляре. А про такие штуки я читал только по теме "квантовая запутанность"

Comment: "дублировать свой "второй фактор"" - ограничение при валидации блоков(в блокчейне) на количество лайков в блоке от одного пользователя, и, если раздал свой ключ: Предоставить возможность решать другим - это тоже вроде как выбор. Но я так понимаю что вы про то, что нужно какое-то восстановление своего доступа. Чтобы, к примеру, если такая авторизация происходит по средствам аутентификации голоса(такая наверняка не сработает- чисто для примера), то можно было-бы заставлять каждый раз произносить новую фразу, когда хочешь сменить пароль от своей цифровой подписи. Или вы про что?

Comment: *Очевидно, "дистанционно" этого не сделать никак. Если хорошо симулировать - никто не отличит симумяцию от человека.* Ну тут позвольте немножко не согласиться - примеры успешной идентификации имеются. Наиболее показательный - госуслуги. Человек оставляет следы, которые можно сверить. Другое дело, что не каждому это доступно - аутентификация через госуслуги... *Но сложная часть задачи - осталась: как препятствовать этому человеку раздать свою пловинку ключа еще куче людей или виртуальных личностей?* Вот тут-то как раз какая-то собака порылась. И до сих пор я не видел работающего решения.

Comment: "а таких, которые "на самом деле" существуют в единственном экземпляре" - или какая-то информация, которую можно извлекать из человека многократно разными способами, как в примере с аутентификацией с помощью речи, но текущий вариант правильной "фразы" определяется состоянием блокчейна.  Т.е. сам человек должен выступать в роли подсказки для обращения(обратная хешированию операция) Хеш-функции.